# Passing objects between AuthorizeAttribute and Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, authorization

To authorize a GET request for an item by Id, I query for the item in a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` to verify the authenticated user has access. To prevent duplicating the query in the `ApiController` action, I want to pass the object from the `AuthorizeAttribute` to the action.

Since the `AuthorizeAttribute` is called in the pipeline before the `ActionArgument` binders have run, I cannot pass the object via `HttpActionContext.ActionArguments`. I am also wary of serializing it into a querystring and potentially running up against the length limit.

One option for passing the item is stashing it in `HttpContext.Current.Items` and casting it upon retrieval in the action. I have read that this will work even in asynchronous actions, but there seems to be considerable advice against using the `Items` dictionary.

Should I simply re-query for the item in the action? Is using the `Items` dictionary appropriate? Is it appropriate to use an `ActionFilterAttribute` for this purpose to allow for access to `HttpActionContext.ActionArguments` even though I am using it for authorization? Is there another vector that I have overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Properties` dictionary of `HttpRequestMessage`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Any reason this is more appropriate than `HttpContext.Items`? Based on MSDN definitions, it seems like `Items` would be more appropriate since it specifically mentions sharing data between interfaces. I was starting to lean towards `Items` since most advice against it referenced avoiding coupling with a specific (Web) implementation, yet the `AuthorizeAttribute` would seem to already be coupled with Web.Http/Web.Mvc.

Not sure about the validitity, but I also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646828/performance-issues-when-accessing-httprequestmessage-properties-collection-in-we

Comment: Couple of reasons - easy to unit test and host-agnostic. By using `HttpContext`, you are locking yourself to web-hosting (IIS/ASP.NET). `HttpContext.Current` is going to be null if you are going to, for example, host it using OWIN.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code

```
 protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
            {
                BaseApiController baseApi = actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller as BaseApiController;
                baseApi.Property = 10;
            }
```